# nginx default SSL SNI host overwrites SSL Protocols

Tags: nginx, ssl, protocol

I have setup nginx with SSL (SNI based).

My first served vHost uses

```
server {
...
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name host1;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
....
```

On others vhosts I wanted to be stricter and only allow `TLSv1.2`

```
server {
...
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name host2;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
....
```

However, whatever I specify in all host configs except the first one, they all have no effect. The only change that occurs is when I change the first vhost.
So `host2` ends up with: `TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2`

It works also the other way round:

- Only specify TLSv1.2 in first vhost
- Specify all protocols in upcoming vhosts
- Result is, all vhosts only use TLSv1.2

Is it not possible to use different protocols on different SSL SNI vhosts?

Comment: Do you have `ssl_ciphers` and/or `ssl_prefer_server_ciphers` in vhosts?

Comment: Yes all vhosts have `ssl_prefer_server_ciphers` positively defined and also use either different or the same `ssl_ciphers` (Doesn't matter if they are the same or different, already tried)

Comment: Not so much same v different but specifically what ciphers. If you only enter tlsv1.2 chipers and you prefer server it will only be tls1.2.

Comment: I guess that's because SSL handshake occurs before nginx knows hostname, so it uses default one

Comment: @AlexeyTen however, it works for different ciphers... Any explanation on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can nginx use different SSL protocols in different server blocks?](https://serverfault.com/questions/627639/can-nginx-use-different-ssl-protocols-in-different-server-blocks)